# why does NUnit test project doesn't recognize as a project in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

when creating NUnit test project the solution explorer does not show any project and when choosing it it does not contain (.net framework)
I try every thing I could find on the internet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDRFi.png)

How can I make the NUnit projec in Visual Studio 2022 Community?